# Setting tbody attributes when rendering Ember.CollectionView into table

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use a CollectionView to display a list of elements in a table. I need to add a class and data attribute in the tbody element. When I do something like :

```
App.ListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
   tagName: 'table',
   classNameBindings: ['myClass'],

  myClass: "my-class"
})
```

It only sets the class of the table element but not the tbody element. How can I set class and other attributes in the tbody element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tbody` as tagName and nest it inside a `<table>` element, see http://jsfiddle.net/AKEsR/

**Handlebars:**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    <table>
        {{#collection App.ListView}}
            <td>{{content}}</td>
        {{/collection}}
    </table>
</script>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    classNameBindings: ['myClass'],
    myClass: "my-class",
    content: Ember.A(['a', 'b'])
});​
```